# Where can I find a steering stick in Zelda: Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I'm looking for a steering stick so I can save a hoverbike design to Autobuild. However, I haven't found any and don't know where I would encounter one. To be clear, I'm looking for an easily accessible steering stick just lying around. I don't need it as a zonai capsule, I just need 1 to build the bike for the first time.

Comment: What's wrong with a Zonai Capsule? Then you can have it anywhere you want it.

Comment: I just need one. I'm interested in easy access, and the zonai capsules are farther away from the center of the map (at least I think they are)

Comment: You can get Zonai Capsules at any of those dispenser things. They even tell you which types of capsules they dump-out, though you can't predict exactly which ones you get each time. I usually just dump 5 charges in and get a bunch of each thing. Then you have them wherever you need them. I make it a point to feed every dispenser I meet to see what capsules it contains so I can go back and get a specific subset whenever I need to re-stock. They are always located next to shrines, so they are always easy to get to.

Comment: I know how device dispensers work. The problem is that I haven't found any with steering sticks.

Comment: Also, I know that if you find a device dispenser that you like, you can stick 5 large zonai charges in to get 60 items.

Comment: Most of the zonai construction outposts in the depths will have one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my first one on the Great Plateau, but a very easy one to get to is right outside Outskirt Stable, just to the South West of Hyrule Field. It's situated near an almost complete vehicle made with big wheels and a stone slab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was one at one of the stables adjacent to the central region, but wasn't sure which one.

Answer (score 4):

The digsite west of Tarry Town has plenty of freestanding Zonai devices, including a Steering stick.

(You can even use the vehicle racing course to test out your device immediately afterwards!)